# Trying to find the last row of a table through xpath while using selenium python while using an if statement

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to create a function that checks through all the table rows within a page, and stores and tells you the number of the last row that's been reached. The if statement keeps running through the else outcome(once it reaches the last row the function stops). I'm having problems finding a way for the function to enter the if condition.
Thanks and sorry for the messy code, beginner here.

```
def lastRowFinder():
for e in range(1, 100):
    tableRowElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphContenido_gridSeleccionados']/tbody/tr" + str([e]))
    tableRowNumber = e 
    LastRow = driver.find_elements_by_id("id='ctl00_cphContenido_gridSeleccionados']/tbody/tr" + str([e]))
    if selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(LastRow) == False:
        print("Row not found")
    else: 
        e = e + 1
        print(tableRowNumber)
```

Comment: It looks like you're finding the same (first) row 100 times. Try `find_elements_by_xpath(..)` to return all the rows in a list and remove the loop.

Comment: I don't think that's the case: I used 100 as the range since that would be the max amount of possible rows(it's an appointment based table so the rows will decrease with time). However I get the actual amount of current rows when I run the code.

Comment: My mistake. I missed the counter. Based on the docs, LastRow should be an empty list if the element is not found. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'll look into it!

Comment: /tr" + str([e]) -> /tr[{}]".format(str(e)) should be.

Comment: Where should this be applied?

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the number of tr's in the table? Try:

```
driver.execute_script("""
  return document.querySelectorAll('#table_id tr').length
""")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be returning any values, tried to have it return values in str() and int() forms but nothing. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a bit of Javasript/jQuery.
In my example I want to find the last row and find the edit icon and click that.

```
browser.execute_script("let lastrow = $('table').find('tr')[document.querySelectorAll('table tr').length-1];$(lastrow).find('.fa-edit').click();")
```